# SpringData JPA is not refreshing or clear the cache, when table is updated from outside resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, repository, entitymanager

I'm working on SpringBoot Jpa to interact with DB tables, in few of my JPA repository I am getting old version of JPA Entity(Not Updated) when other applications updated that particular database table from outside, JPA is not able to give updated dataset. I tried using EntityManager.clear(), entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll(); but not of them working.

At the end, I had to create a new entityManager object from entityManagerFactory and run the native SQL to get the updated output. But this is not a good practice for my project as it makes my JPA dependent on Native SQL. So, please let me know if there is anything I am missing or should do to reflect the latest changes from my JPA repository at run time.
 Or is there any way from which I can run JPA repository from newly created entitymanager object?

```
 entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll(); //Autowired from persistenceContext
        entityManager.clear();
        EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `@Transactional` annotation to the Service.

Also, make sure you're having a single entity instance.

Comment: please share more details so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the bellow code:

> entityManager.flush();

Comment: Tried it, still no luck